# Select2: Multiple select elements constrained

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to achieve something and I can't find/decide what is the best way to do it, so i'm going to ask if somebody did this before or if select2 has something built in in order to achieve what I want.

Heres the thing: I have a number of select (multiple) elements in my DOM, lets say 5, all share the same options, but, If one of the selects has an option selected, I want the others to hide/remove/avoid being selected, I would like to constrain all selects in order to avoid having the same value selected in 2 different selects. I am not asking for a full code solution, I just need to know if someone already did it (if yes, would be nice to get it shared in order for future developers that stumble upon this can see the solution), or if select2 has the functionallity.

What I have done so far is:

```
       $('.constrainedSelect').each(function(i, select) {    
            var selectedValue = $(select).select2("val");
            var options = $('#allOptions').find('option').clone();

            if (selectedValue.length !== 0) {
                options.each(function(i, option) {
                    if($(select).find('option[value="' + $(option).val() + '"]').length !== 1) {
                        $(select).append(option);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                options.push($("<option />", {value: e.choice.id.trim(), text: e.choice.text.trim()})[0]);
                $(select).html(options);
            }
        });
```

But thats just a concept and its really buggy.

The version of select2 i'm using (and need to use, no time to change it in production yet) is `Version: 3.5.2 Timestamp: Sat Nov  1 14:43:36 EDT 2014`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can select as many as you like, but once you select one option, it must dissappear from all other selects, and if you remove one option, it should reapper in all other selects. I guess it could be done pretty simple and in like 20+ lines of code or maybe less. I'm working on a solution now, if nobody posts a solution, I will share mine.

Comment: Based on your requirements, mine is too complicated to be of use to you *as-is*. If anyone posts an answer I will see if I can simply improve theirs/yours based on my previous work :) +1 for a question I expected to see a long time ago!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a nice way to do this, if anyone was wondering how, I think this is a good approach but I would like to see comments and if somebody wants to improve my answer, feel free to copy the code and paste it in a separate answer, if the approach gets better I will accept that answer. Thanks guys for the help.

```
        var $selects = $(".constrainedSelects");
        $selects.on('change', function(e) {
            var selectedValues = $(this).select2('val');
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedValues.length; i++) {
                $selects.not(this).find("option[value='" + selectedValues[i] + "']").attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });

        $selects.on('select2-removed', function(e) {
            $selects.find("option[value='" + e.val + "']").attr('disabled', false);
        });
```

Here is a fiddle to show the result: http://jsfiddle.net/rv38f0v6/

Comment: Can you apply this to a JSFiddle etc? I was given the impression the `disabled` property was unreliable across browsers (but I need to test it).

Comment: Actually that is a good solution for the case outlined, but it does not appear to work at all with latest IE :(

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, i'm currently working on Linux so I could not test that in a "real" IE (Even though IE is not a browser :p)

Comment: If it gets used to browse... it's a browser (regardless of personal opinions of it) :)

Answer (score -1):

Please See if this helps! this is a jquery validation method to avoid same values in different select boxes.

```
 $.validator.addMethod("valOption", function(value, element) {
         var curValue,
             allElems,
             counter,
             totalCount = 0;

         curValue = value;
         allElems = $('#myPage select');
         for (counter = 0; counter < allElems.length; counter = counter + 1) {
             if (curValue === allElems.eq(counter).val()) {
                 totalCount = totalCount + 1;
             }
         }
         if (totalCount === 1) {
             return this.optional(element) || (true);
         } else {
             return (false);
         }
     }, "Please select different option");
```

Comment: And how would I implement this?

Comment: I did not stated that I was using the jquery validation plugin. My tags where "jquery", "javascript", "select2".

Comment: jquery, not jquery validation plugin. Sorry if i was unclear.

Answer (score -2):

```
 $(document).on('change', '.constrainedSelect', function() {
    var changedSelect = $(this);
    $(".constrainedSelect").not(changedSelect).select2("val", "").select2("enable", false)
});
```

I think something like this event listener would take care of it.  It makes sure the val of all the others are empty and then disables them so they cannot be selected from.

**How about this instead:**

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f72tfj4x/)

```
//setup trackign array and block duplicate selections
var selectedIds = [];
 $(document).on('select2-selecting', '.constrainedSelect', function(event) {
    var idx = $.inArray(event.val, selectedIds);
    if(idx === -1) {
        selectedIds.push(event.val);
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

//remove selected item from our tracking array
 $(document).on('select2-removed', '.constrainedSelect', function(event) {
    var idx = $.inArray(event.val, selectedIds);
    selectedIds.splice(idx,1);
});
```

Comment: The OP meant that any selected options (multiples are allowed), in other lists, be removed from all other lists. Not that only one selection is valid at a time. e.g. you can select `Zebra` in the first list and the `Zebra` option vanishes from all other lists.

Comment: This just disables all my selects. And I don't want the other selects to get empty, I want only the options that are selected in other selects to hide/dissapear/disable

Comment: I see, sorry for the misunderstanding.  I will think about it some more and see if I can come up with something else.

Comment: @taxicala updated with a different answer if you want to check it out.

Comment: You may wish to provide a demo (JSFiddle etc), to show that it actually does what you think it does :)

Comment: This is not what I was looking for, you are just adding/removing the values to an array, how would this make the selects avoid selecting an already selected value?

Comment: This uses the "avoid being selected" method.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP (and most users) do not like the "avoid being selected" method. They need to know in advance not to select those options. Any solution should remove, or at least disable, the unwanted options from all other lists in the set.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie well the op put it in his list of items.  I think the data can be tweaked to add a disabled property and pushed back onto the selects.  Then remove the property on the delete.